# Is it required to get a wakelock for an Android service with an active LocationListener?

Tags: android, service, geolocation, wakelock, locationlistener

In my application, I have a service that has an active LocationListener and sends the location over the air. When the service is running, the phone never goes to sleep, and it keeps sending the locations, even though I don't have a wakelock. This is exactly what I want, but I was wondering if that's the expected behavior. I couldn't find any information on this in the SDK documentation. Can I rely on it, or is it safer to get my own wakelock ?

Answer (score 1):

Running location services continuously is battery consuming.User do not like apps that consume their battery and they wont think twice before deleting the app.Best idea is to wake up service only when needed.
[Please check this link for more information on battery usage trade offs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Comment: Thanks Mukund, but this is a real-time application and requires continuous monitoring of the position.